# Re-use a global function within a class decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Suppose I have a function that generates a router function which invokes specified callbacks depending on whether a number is odd or even:

```
def odd_even_router(odd, even):
    def r(n):
        if n % 2:
            odd(n)
        else:
            even(n)
    return r
```

I also have a class decorator that attaches a similar router method, named `check_number`, to a class:

```
def attach_default_router(cls):
    def route(self, n):
        if n % 2:
            self.on_odd(n)
        else:
            self.on_even(n)

    cls.check_number = route
    return cls
```

Then, a class decorated with `@attach_default_router` has `check_number()` defined automatically, and only has to implement `on_odd()` and `on_even()`:

```
@attach_default_router
class A(object):
    def on_odd(self, n):
        print 'Odd number'

    def on_even(self, n):
        print 'Even number'
```

If I want to re-use `odd_even_router()`, the router function generator, inside `attach_default_router()`, I may do this:

```
def attach_default_router(cls):
    def route(self, n):
        r = odd_even_router(self.on_odd, self.on_even)
        r(n)

    cls.check_number = route
    return cls
```

However, an undesirable effect is that, every time `check_number()` gets called, a new (but identical) router function is generated. So here is my question: **How could I re-use `odd_even_router()` generator inside `attach_default_router()` decorator, but without generating a new router function every time?**

The issue at heart is: `odd_even_router()` returns a function that takes one argument, but `check_number()`, being an instance method, needs two (the first being the object's `self`). If I don't get hold of `self`, I cannot generate the router function yet. When I get hold of `self`, I am already inside the method, and generating it there entails generating every time the method is called.

How could I resolve this dilemma?

Comment: Have you considered using mixins instead of class decorators?

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the term "mixin". After looking it up, I'd say it is just multiple inheritance. Well, I did consider multiple inheritance, but I have an (somewhat irrational) adversity to it. In my case, the classes to be decorated are all extensions from some other classes already, so my instinct is to avoid inheriting from more than one thing. But yes, it is an option. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you'd have to bind your `odd` and `even` hooks at runtime, requiring a slightly different implementation of your factory.

That's because not only is your `route` function produced a-new each time, *so are the `odd` and `even` methods. `self.odd` creates a new method wrapper every time you execute that expression, because [functions are descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), and are being bound to the instance (`self` here) each time you need one.

So, if you want to generate *one* `route()` function for use with all instances of your decorated class, you have to then manually make sure the binding still takes place:

```
def odd_even_router_method_factory(odd, even):
    def route(self, n):
        if n % 2:
            odd.__get__(self)(n)
        else:
            even.__get__(self)(n)
    return route

def attach_default_router(cls):
    route = odd_even_router_method_factory(cls.on_odd, cls.on_even)
    cls.check_number = route
    return cls
```

Note that Python *still will create a `route` method object* now. Each time you access `instance_of_your_decorated_class.route`, a method object is created through the descriptor protocol. And the same happens when calling `odd.__get__()` and `even.__get__()`. You may as well stick to your original version, and generate a new `route()` function for each call, passing in `self.odd` and `self.even`, as that's probably more readable, and keeps your original `odd_even_router()` factory function usable for use both as methods and for functions.

Comment: Just a reminder: you forgot `return route` in the factory function. Thank you. I guess, like most engineering problems, there is no "perfect" solutions, only tradeoffs.

Comment: Oops, return statement added. Indeed; although engineering with Python feels a lot more like fun to me :-)